# How to reinitialize a HashSet partial class in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have following partial class generated by mvc with database first method.
How do i remove reinitialize the hashset class so that i can set default value to it?

**Original class generated by mvc**

```
 public partial class GeneratedClass
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public GeneratedClass()
    {
        this.GeneratedClass= new HashSet<GeneratedClass>();

    }}
```

**my data anotation partial class**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(GeneratedClassAttribute))]
public partial class GeneratedClass
{
    public GeneratedClass()
    {
        MyPropertyValue = "default value";
    }
}
```

**error throw**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'GeneratedClass' and 'GeneratedClass'

**Updated working code**

Thanks to  Tetsuya Yamamoto for pointing out creating 2 constructor with same parameter.so i added a dummy parameter and bomb it works.

```
 public GeneratedClass(string dummyValue="")
```

**Working 2**
by Kirk Woll

using `OnCreate`

Comment: Partial class will compile as a single class - you're declaring 2 constructors in same class with no parameters but with different contents (potentially naming conflict). Remove the second constructor and see if it works, also look at MSDN docs about partial classes => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx.

Comment: they are in different files.As i do not want to change system generated file/codes therefore i create another partial class to add on metadatetypes like `[Display(Name = "Greeting")] [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]`  removing the second constructor will work but i need to set default value therefore i need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tetsuya described in his comment, partial classes are mostly syntactic sugar for splitting the implementation of a single class into multiple files.  So except for a few specific extensibility points (basically partial methods), you can't declare a member with the same name in both files.

To clarify, it's possible for the (usually generated) class to define a "partial" method:

```
partial void Foo();
```

But unless the member explicitly supports the `partial` modifier, you can't declare that member in multiple files.  I'm not sure how much you control the generated constructor, but *ideally* it would define an `OnCreated` partial method like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
public GeneratedClass()
{
    this.GeneratedClass= new HashSet<GeneratedClass>();
    OnCreated();
}

partial void OnCreated();
```

Then in your "data anotation partial class" you would implement that `OnCreated` partial method:

```
private void OnCreated()
{
    MyPropertyValue = "default value";
}
```

Now the order of operations is clear.  (which constructor should get invoked before the other if your original syntax were in fact supported?)  The actual constructor executes, and it delegates any subsequent initialization to the partial method (which is allowed to be unimplemented).

Comment: OnCreated seems to be more elegant.Adopted and works. Thanks Kirk Woll